# What is the detailed difference between two Python codes, both written to find the largest number among three inputs

Tags: python, if-statement, comparison

How can I understand detailed difference between below two codes written to find the largest number among three numbers.

Code1:

```
def max_num(num1, num2, num3):
    if num1 >= num2 and num1 >= num3:
        return num1
    elif num2 >= num1 and num2 >= num3
        return num2
    else:
        return num3
```

Code2:

```
def max_num(num1, num2, num3):
    if num1 > num2 and num1 > num3:
        return num1
    elif num2 > num1 and num2 > num3
        return num2
    else:
        return num3
```

Comment: What precisely don't you understand? Do you know what `>` and `>=` do? Have you tested them out?

Comment: Code1 is written by me when I wanted to write this function. I found Code2 online for the same purpose. Also, both are working. But, I am not able to understand what can be the difference between them. Both work, but, is there any kind of used case I am missing?

Comment: It would be very difficult to detect, because if two numbers are equal do you care which one is considered the max?

Comment: No, I don't care which number is returned in case they are similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Code2 could erroneously return num3 as max if num1 == num2, ie in [6, 6, 5].

The main difference, as commented above, is the use of "greater than" vs "greater or equal". I think the only place this would matter is when you have multiple values in the list which are equal, in which case Code2 would return the first instance, whereas Code3 would return the last.

Comment: I am really sorry, and I know this a silly question, But, I am not able to understand what you said (specifically 2nd statement in your comment)

Comment: Ok, let's say the three numbers you send to the function are [6, 6, 5]. In Code1, this would return 6. However, in the case of Code2, it would return 5 because it fails both the second and third conditional statements.

Comment: Thank you very much. After commenting on your code, I also tried different cases and found this issue. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to be of help!